# Python 3.7 Pycharm Community Edition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I couldn't find out what is the bug that is causing this error. I am using Python 3.7. The code is self-explanatory :

```
TaxPay = (((SimpleFacialPrice * 5) + (HerbalFacialPrice * 8) + (AcneFacialPrice * 10) +(SmartFacialPrice * 12) + (DeliveryCost * 12)) * 0.2))
Cost = (((SimpleFacialPrice * 5) + (HerbalFacialPrice * 8) + (AcneFacialPrice * 10) +(SmartFacialPrice * 12) + (DeliveryCost * 12)))
CostofItems = "$ " + str("%.2f" % (TaxPay + Cost))
TotalCost.set(CostofItems)

y = random.randint(10034, 699812)
randomRef = str(y)
PaymentRef.set("BILL" + randomRef)
```

On the end of every line it is giving the same error

> "end of the statement expected"

Comment: Looks like those parentheses on the first line aren't balanced.  You have an extra closing bracket at the end.

Comment: @Daniyal : There is extra ")" parenthesis at the end of the first statement, remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont you think this statement has extra paranthesis ")" TaxPay = (((SimpleFacialPrice * 5) + (HerbalFacialPrice * 8) + (AcneFacialPrice * 10) +(SmartFacialPrice * 12) + (DeliveryCost * 12)) * 0.2))

Comment: OMG , How couldn't I see that..

Comment: Thankyou so much :) You're the best (y)